# Using JavaScript with WkWebView - error on UserMessageHandler

Tags: javascript, swift, webview, wkwebview

When sending a message through Javascript to iOS, I encountered this error message that I can't find any information online: "Can only call UserMessageHandler.postMessage on instances of UserMessageHandler".

I am using a webview to render a webpage on iOS.

I tried adding the same script from native code and I was able to receive the message. However, the same script shows the above error if I deploy it on the web site.

```
let scriptSource = "window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage({command: 'command goes here'});"
let userScript = WKUserScript(source: scriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
```

on the web end, I used the following code

```
key: "onExit",
                    value: function() {
                        var t = function() {
                            try {
                                return window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage || null
                            } catch (t) {
                                return null
                            }
                        }();
                        if (t)
                            try {
                                t({
                                    command: "command goes here"
                                }), console.log("window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage called successfully")
                            } catch (t) {
                                console.log("error thrown when calling window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage - " + (t || {}).message)
                            }
                        else
                            console.log("window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage not found!")
                    }
```

Comment: What did you find out?

Answer (score 2):

Explicit bind `this` will resolve the error:

```js
window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler.postMessage.bind(window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsHandler)
```